# ¿Como "empaquetar" un proyecto en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel el cual quisiera "empaquetar" en un zip de tal forma que sea más sencillo de utilizar en hosting con cpanel. Como saben, con laravel es necesario instalar la dependencias vía composer, sin embargo muchas de esas dependencias solo son necesarias durante el desarrollo. Además de que en muchas ocasiones no puedes instalar Composer en servidores con cpanel, sobre todo cuando son baratos o gratuitos.

El proyecto que estoy haciendo esta pensado para que otras personas puedan descargarlo y usarlo tipo Wordpress. Así que me gustaría quitar todo lo que no es necesario para producción.

Lo más sencillo y obvio en comprimir todo y a volar, pero esto haría que el resultado final pese demasiado y eso no es lo que busco. Quiero que el zip resultante sea lo mas ligero posible y con el mínimo de archivos necesarios.

Lo segundo más obvio es ignorar la carpeta vendor pero eso causaría que el sistema falle. ¿Saben de alguna forma de omitir las carpetas que no sean estrictamente necesarias? No busco hacer una discusión, más que nada busco alternativas eficaces que no me haga perder 3 horas borrando carpetas y testeando a ver si no fallo algo.

Answer (score 1):

Curiosamente veo en el enunciado que casi que respondiste tú mismo la pregunta, y realmente para alguien que haya trabajado con Laravel esto debería ser algo sencillo.

Carpetas innecesarias en producción:

- **database**: Dependiendo si puedes ejecutar o no las migraciones en el servidor se puede obviar esta carpera, lo más sencillo puede ser almacenar todo el sql respectivo en archivos planos en una carpeta como tools, o como te parezca mejor llamarla.
- **storage**: Salvo que necesites algo de lo que puedas tener almacenado en la carpeta app, la puedes obviar también (normalmente nada de lo que se tiene en desarrollo en esa carpeta es necesario, ni debería serlo).
- **tests**: Normalmente no necesitas ejecutar tests en producción, así que es seguro borrarla

En cuanto a **vendor**, sí es necesaria esta carpeta (tal y como lo explicas en la pregunta), pero no son necesarias todas las dependencias como también lo explicas. Hay varias formas de solo tener las dependencias de producción: una es teniendo dos instancias locales (o en los stages de desarrollo) y en una de estas tener solo las dependencias de producción, otra forma sería hacerlo con un script de deploy, y bueno, realmente hay muchas formas de solucionar esto sin afectar el ambiente de desarrollo.

En mi opinión no vale la pena entrar en los detalles de qué archivos o subcarpetas pueden servir o no, y lo puedes manejar con git de ser necesario.

Por último, en cuanto a los archivos ubicados en la raíz, su tamaño es muy pequeño. Los únicos que serían estrictamente necesarios son: artisan, composer.json, .env.example (este último para que la persona que lo descargue tenga una guía de como configurar su .env).

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta Shaz, la verdad es que he trabajado antes con Laravel pero nunca me había preocupado este tipo de cosas ya que suelo trabajar con Amazon o DigitalOcean y pues clono, hago composer install y listo. Siempre supe que no era la mejor manera de trabajar pero me funcionaba, ahora si que necesito empaparme más a fondo con toda esta movida. De momento tomare en cuenta tu recomendación pero seguiré investigando sobre este asunto. Saludos!

Comment: No es una recomendación lo que estoy dando (no son válidas en StackOverflow), estoy dando una respuesta sustentada.

Comment: Muy cierto, mi culpa por la confusión. Investigue un poquito y lo combine con tu respuesta. Creo que el resultado se acerca bastante a lo que tenia en mente, asi que de momento así lo trabajare. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar un rato y apoyado en la respuesta de Shaz llegue a algo muy cercano a lo que buscaba. Dejo el procedimiento completo por si es de utilidad a otras personas.

El primer paso es obviamente tener la aplicación lista para producción o por lo menos una versión estable. Ahora hay de dos sopas, o creas una nueva rama en tu repositorio local (en caso de que estés usando git) o bien clonas la carpeta del proyecto en tu computadora. Una tercera opción seria clonar el proyecto desde GitHub o lo que uses. Yo para realizar pruebas me fui por la segunda opción por ser más simple y comoda en ese momento.

Así que ahora tenia la carpeta del proyecto de desarrollo `SISGEC` y la carpeta que distribuiré lista para usar a la cual llamé `SISGEC-Prod`. Una vez hecho esto entre a la carpeta de producción y ejecute el comando `composer install --no-dev`, el cual ayuda a eliminar cualquier cosa que no se esté utilizando para ejecutar la aplicación. Esto ultimo lo encontré en la contraparte en ingles de este sitio. Creo que su autor Sven lo explica mejor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35452284/8067370

El resultado fue una carpeta `vendor` mucho más limpia y con menos dependencias. Paso de tener **43** dependencias a tener solo **29**.

[image: Comparativa antes de optimizar la carpeta vendor vs despues]

Siguiendo la respuesta de Shaz borre las siguientes carpetas y archivos:

- .DS_Store
- .editorconfig
- .env.travis
- .travis.yml
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- phpunit.xml
- tests
- storage
- resources
- node_modules

En mi caso borro la carpeta resources por que en sí no necesito que los recursos se puedan modificar una vez se lance a producción, así que unicamente dejo la carpeta `public` en donde ya están todos los archivos procesados por webpack que necesita el sistema para funcionar.

La diferencia entre la carpeta original y la que hemos modificado es brutal, pasando de 95MB a solo 24MB sus respectivos archivos comprimidos.

[image: Comparativa de ambas carpetas ya comprimidas]

Para mi este resultado es más que suficiente y el proceso no es tan complicado, quizás se pueda automatizar de alguna forma aunque de momento no estoy seguro como. Lo que sí es que no toma mas de 10 min. hacerlo lo cual esta bastante bien.

Como consideración extra, si estas usando bases de datos lo que menciona Shaz es que lo más sencillo puede ser almacenar todo el sql respectivo en archivos planos. Yo me salte este paso de momento ya que estoy haciendo un auto-installer el cual cubrirá esta parte.

Saludos!